# Vector is too large for a data.frame

Tags: r, memory, dataframe, storage

I have developed a list of x,y coordinates... of which I have tens of millions and I'm unable to store/manipulate them as a data.frame due to limited RAM.  How can an R newbee use the available data?

I've tried to store them within a txt file but still having troubles. I'm grateful for your thoughts.

EDITS:  A little background here... I'm modeling individual pellets of material spread across a field.  The scattering function is looped, each time appending data to the data.frame that holds the x,y components.

```
mydata_x <- append(mydata_x,rnorm(number,x,sd))
mydata_y <- append(mydata_y,rnorm(number,y,sd))
    df <- data.frame(x=mydata_x,y=mydata_y)
```

Comment: Where is this list of coordinates currently? Do you have vectors of each of them, or are they in a `list()` (you use the word "list" but it's not clear you mean the data structure). What code are you using to try to put them in a data frame?

Comment: Don't "grow" objects, you are in Circle 2 of [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: You should check out the "Large memory and out-of-memory data" section of the HPC Task View. https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html

Comment: I'm grateful for the references, and the lessons learned from them.  However, I'm too far down this rabbit hole to start over.  Is there a way to store and use these large objects from the disk-drive?  I've been reading about ffdf {ff}, but haven't found an example to help me apply it.